# Append function output to top of created file

Tags: bash

I have a script running in linux which is simply multiple function calls outputted into a file.  I have a function which is an overview of important information That I would like to append to the top of the file for easy viewing.

The problem is that I cannot simply call this overview function first because it is dependant on previous functions.

Is there an easier way to do this without creating a temp file?  This is a fairly large file and that would take pretty long.

Comment: One way is to create a new file, insert the gathered info, then concatenate everything else from the old file after it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using something like a Perl script, it should be possible to first leave some space at the top for the overview, then write all your data.

After this, reopen the file with write/append (w+) access, move the filehandle position to the desired position early in the file, using seek() or sysseek() functions, then write the overview data to it.

Help on Perl functions can be obtained here: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html

Answer (score 0):

First of all, perhaps you meant prepend, not append.

In linux, suppose you want:
file1 -> BottomContent
file2 -> TopContent

You could use:

```
$ cat file2 file1 > finalfile; rm file[12]
```

Answer (score 0):

@SandeepY has one reasonable solution.

Any time you modify a file in Unix, you're using a system that is opening your original file and an new file, so there's (almost always) a temporary file involved, whether you can see it or not.

That being said, another solution, as you specfied a function is providing some output, is to use a process group to "marshall" your output into one stream, and redirect that into your file.

```
 mv mainFile mainFile.tmp
 {
   myFunc 
   cat mainFile.tmp
 } > mainFile && /bin/rm mainFile.tmp
```

As you seem to need this regularly, it should be easy to turn this into a function, replacing mainFile with `"$1"`.

IHTH